# Boketh plot hide html site and show output only in Jupyter?

Tags: python, bokeh

With the bokeh package, I created a graph visualization and with `show(plot)` the output is shown in Jupyter but also at the same time a new tab in the browser is opened with the output. I only want to plot it in a Jupyter cell without opening the plot as a new html file. Is this somehow possible?

```
#Booketh plot
output_file("thisisaplot.html")
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/jupyter.html#userguide-jupyter), you should be able to do that by calling `output_notebook()` before calling `show()`.

**Note:** As pointed out by @bigreddot, if you were using `output_file` in the kernel, changing to `output_notebook` may not take place right away. You will need to either call `reset_output()`, or restart your kernel for the change to take place.

Comment: Nope, is still opening a new tab with the plot.

Comment: Replacing `output_file()` in your code by `output_notebook()` does not do it?

Comment: even then, it is always showing the plot in a secondary tab too.

Comment: `output_file` begins a continuous *mode* of operation. Once you call it, all output will go to files (and possibly notebook cells too if you *also* have called `output_notebook`). You will need to either restart your kernel, and then *not* call `output_file`, or call `reset_output` explicitly to turn it off.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. But how can I still save the plot as a html file and use ```output_notebook``` in the same cell?

Comment: Call `save` https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=show#bokeh.io.save BTW I have upvoted the answer because, with respect to your actual original question,which asked ***"only want to plot it in a Jupyter cell"*** it is entirely correct. I hope you consider respecting the responder and upvoting and accepting it.